# How to create optimal cut-off scores for a test placing students into different courses

Tags: probability, logistic, roc, consistency, threshold

Edit: Shared [my solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/624830/97380) as an answer here

Our goal is to determine optimal cut-off test scores for course placement. The course placement has already been manually assigned to each test-taker. The goal is to replace this manual labor with the calculated cut-off test scores, so that a future test-taker from a similar group will be automatically placed into an optimal course.

We're looking for cut-off scores such as this:

- 0-9: Course A
- 10-14: Course B
- 15-19: Course C
- 20-24: Course D
- 25-30: Course E

In this example, if a student answers 14 questions correctly, they'd be placed into Course B.

The variables in this analysis are

- Independent: The screening test score, which is a continuous variable ranging from 0-30
- Dependent: Course placement, which is an ordinal variable, or a categorical variable for which there is a clear ordering of the category labels (i.e. Course B is more advanced than Course A, Course C is more advanced than Course B, and so forth).

Approaches we've considered, along with our concerns about them:

- Set the cut-off score for a specific course at one standard deviation above the median score for all the students who got placed into that course. (This uses the median instead of the mean, because there are some outliers in the data where some students who scored really high got placed into a low-level course).

  - Concerns: Imbalanced data. One of the courses had a disproportionately higher number of students placed into it, which inflates the accuracy of placement.
- Ordinal logistic regression — We've used this model to obtain the probabilities of being in a specific course, given a test score.

  - Concerns: These are probabilities and some of them overlap equally, so how can we decide with certainty which score value the cutoff should fall on? Is regression the correct approach?

[image]

How would you recommend we go about creating cut-off scores for this course placement test and evaluating it?

Comment: To clarify, your data set currently is the score on the screening test and the class they were placed into manually (i.e., regardless of their score on the screening test).  ¿Do you have any additional data?  For example, ¿do you have the scores/passing rates for how the students performed in their assigned classes?

Comment: The dataset contains each question and whether or not the test-taker got it right (0 or 1), along with the total number of questions that they got correct and their final course placement (yes, which was done manually, regardless of their score on the screening test). We don't have data on how the students performed in the courses they were placed in.

Comment: ¿With how large of a sample are you working?

Comment: It's quite small, about 93 students in one group and 200 in another. We're calculating the cutoff scores separately for these groups, as they were placed into two different sets of courses.

Comment: This type of problem falls under the realm of item response theory.  I'm happy to share more if need be.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding of the IRT is that it focuses on the individual item and whether it's a reliable measure of the overall construct. We've done reliability analyses to narrow down the number of questions. I've Googled this a lot, but can't seem to find an established process within IRT to calculate cut-off scores?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146454/discussion-between-anneirb-and-gregg-h).

Comment: Your problem is impossible to solve because its formulation lacks the information needed to understand and operationalize the sense of "optimal." One would think optimality might be framed in terms of the greatest net good for the student population, but how exactly is that determined? How do you propose to trade off the harm in placing a student in an inappropriate course for the benefit of placing other students in appropriate courses? Do you account for any characteristics of the course composition, such as diversity of thought or background? What constraints on course size are there?

Comment: *"which score value the cutoff should fall on? "* On what basis should we be able to decide on these cutoff values? Do you regard the manual placement as a golden standard? Why do your curves show students with the best test scores being placed in the second lowest level course? You could choose some cutoff values, but in any case it seems like you will get a lot different composition of the courses in comparison to your manual process.

Comment: The manual placement would be the golden standard here. My curves are generated from logistic regression model of the probability of being placed into a given course, given the test score. There are some outliers, e.g. these students who got placed into lower-level courses despite having higher scores, or vice versa. We're expected to create cut-off scores given this data, but the process for doing so is not clear to us, because of these overlapping probabilities. We want to prioritize specificity, to reduce negative learning experiences.

Comment: That's a start.  But to make any progress you need to connect -- *quantitatively* -- the test score to some measure of the learning experience.  Absent any connection, an optimal algorithm is to assign students arbitrarily to the classes.  Moreover, if the class sizes are flexible, you also need a quantitative measure of the cost associated with possible class sizes (and that must be commensurate with the learning experience measure).

Comment: Class size is not a concern here. As for some measure of the learning experience, we unfortunately don't have any more data more than what we're given. I think that absent any connection, and an equal chance of being placed into more than one course, it may be possible to find an optimal cut-off if we used a ROC curve here somehow, to prioritize specificity over sensitivity. Is it possible to use a ROC curve given this type of multi-class classification problem?

Comment: @anneirb The use of ROC curves is more a situation when you have positive/negative cases and you want to optimize the benefit of true positives versus the costs of false positives. In your example you do not specify anything that could resemble the relative costs of misclassification in the different classes....

Comment: ...example, in your current figure you could say that a boundary can be placed at a score at 11 for the lowest level class. If you would shift this boundary in any direction, then it will always lead to an increase of misclassification. So you can not optimize anything here. However, if certain classes come at higher or lower cost, or if there is  a difference between being placed in a too low class versus too high class, then you can make some optimization of the boundaries where you balance the errors in classifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> , it may be possible to find an optimal cut-off if we used a ROC curve here somehow, to prioritize specificity over sensitivity

Sensitivity and specificity is a consideration when there is a binary classification and we consider the ability to recognize a particular single class.

Your situation is not exactly like that, as you are considering the classification of multiple classes. Increasing the sensitivity of one class will decrease the sensitivity of the other classes.

For example, when you shift the lowest boundary and increase the number of placements into the PST301 class, then this increases the sensitivity detecting the students of the PST301 class, but it is decreasing the sensitivity of all the other classes.

In order to make an optimization you need some quantitative expression to optimize. This expression should help to answer questions like: What are the pro's and con's of misclassifying a particular class and how do they compare? Is it worth to increase the sensitivity of detecting students for class X at the cost of decreasing the sensitivity of students in class Y?

These questions need to be answered and expressed in a quantitative way, before you can optimize the boundaries.

---

Otherwise, if all things are equal then just use the following classification:

```
0-10: Course A
11-17: Course B
18-30: Course D

removed courses
Course C
Course E
```

This will give the highest number of correct classifications. Any shift of the boundaries will result in less correct classifications.

Choosing to go for less correct classifications might be an option, but it depends on the considerations that quantifies the value of the errors in different classifications. (e.g. if the course A is cheaper then you might place more people in that course, even when it is misclassifying more students in total)

Comment: And there can be more complex considerations. (1) the cost function can be more complex, like considerations as the optimal class sizes which Whuber mentioned in the comments (you say that this is not the case, but it is just an example) (2) the statistical analysis can be more complex if you consider measurement errors, changes in time, etc.

Comment: Your comments about a cost function are helpful. By prioritizing specificity, we aim to minimize the false positive rate, or overplacing students into much higher-level courses. Misclassifying course A into course C should be worse than misclassifying course A into course B. It seems that a cost function that captures this definition of "optimal" may help determine clearer boundaries. Would this cost function be applied during ordinal logistic regression, or to the results?

Comment: @anneirb the problem is also the classification of classes next to each other. How do you compare and quantify misclassifying 'course A into course B' versus misclassifying 'course B into course A'?

Comment: @anneirb the terms specificity and sensitivity are not very clear in this problem. The increase of sensitivity for one category is the decrease of sensitivity for another category. There is no clear way how you wish to combine the sensitivity of different courses.

Comment: *"Would this cost function be applied during ordinal logistic regression, or to the results?"* The easiest approach would be to first fit some probabilities of class membership, as you have done in the image with ordinal regression, and then in a seperate stage figure out boundaries for classification with the results from the regression. Although, of course, you can also do it in one go. The advantage of that would be that you can optimise the fitting method with something like cross validation.

Comment: *the problem is also the classification of classes next to each other.* That's pretty much the question in this post :) I'm doing some reading on how I might create such a cost function. After thinking about it more, I think that it might make more sense to apply the cost function after the logistic regression, since we'd like the logistic regression to operate off the ground truth.

Comment: @anneirb the 'training' of the regression is indeed often optimal when using the likelihood (ie fit the regression), but you might couple it to a second cost function to make small improvements by tuning parameters in the regression that can reduce the variance of the outcome. (A related question where this coupling of two cost functions plays a role is: [Could a mismatch between loss functions used for fitting vs. tuning parameter selection be justified?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369589/))

Comment: *"That's pretty much the question in this post"* A problem with it is that it is not stated in detail. The question currently reads like *"I have a problem that involves a parameter $x$. How do I optimize $x$?"* without telling what it is that needs to be optimized. You might say that the cut-off values are the object that need to be optimized, but those values are just the parameters that can be adjusted to perform the optimization. The object that is to be optimized should be some quantitative function of the cut-off values.

Comment: You minimize "specificity," as you describe it in your initial comment in this thread, by placing everyone in the lowest-level course!  This mathematical fact helps illustrate why it's important to formulate a relevant objective function as well as appropriate constraints.

Answer (score 2):

If courses A, B, C, D, E got $a,b,c,d,e$ manual assignments among the $N=a+b+c+d+e$ students so far, then as a first attempt I would:

- set the upper cutoff for course A at the $a^{th}$-worst of the scores so far;
- set the upper cutoff for course B at the $(a+b)^{th}$-worst of the scores so far;
- set the lower cutoff for course D at the  $(d+e)^{th}$-best of the scores so far;
- set the lower cutoff for course E at the $e^{th}$-best of the scores so far.

So far I don’t see a reason for anything more complicated than that.

Comment: It seems plausible to use the quantiles of the test scores such that a particular ratio of class sizes is obtained. But the last comment 'no reason for anything more complicated' is not so clear. Why is it that these percentiles are optimal? What optimization is performed with it? For all such questions and for the actual underlying cost function to be optimized (which is not stated explicitly in the question but we can see all sorts of reasons for various kinds of approaches with different cost functions), for all that we have reasons for something more complicated.

Comment: I guess this optimized for simplicity. The question omitted the complications that seem likely to me: considering the student’s intended degree, time at the school so far, scores on different parts of the test, etc.

Comment: We don't want to base the cutoffs on class sizes or to have them controlled by that in any way. But I'd also like to optimize for simplicity. This looks like an approach to evaluate, as it gives a cut off of 

A: 0-11, 
B: 12-15, 
C: 16-20, 
D: 21-27, 
E: 28>

Comment: How would this translate to other number of courses, e.g. if we had 3 courses instead of 5?

Comment: Would the accuracy of this be calculated as _correct placements of given course that fit range / all placements that fit the range_ or _correct placements of given course that fit range / all placements of given course_?

Comment: For three courses A, B, C with $a, b, c$ manual placements, I would set the upper cutoff for course A at the $a^{th}$-worst score and the lower cutoff for course C at the $c^{th}$-best score. Meanwhile the metric of accuracy is up to you!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is the following:

1. using a logistic regression of the category regressed on the score of the test.  Find the 50% cut-off for A vs B-or-C-or-D-or-E
2. repeat but find the 50% cut-off for A-or-B vs C-or-D-or-E
3. repeat this process for all cumulative boundary points

But, do not stop here.  Next, obtain information on how well these boundary assignments work for the next batch of students.  For example, ¿did they fare well in their assigned course?  You can revisit the cutoffs using this information.

Finally, if you are so inclined, you can also do an analysis that looks at each question, and how well that question correlates (is associated) with the total score (and by extension the cut-off scores).  If there are certain questions that demonstrate high discrimination, these items can be highlighted for later use as "drop-dead" boundaries.  These are separate from the thresholds, and are must-pass questions to make to a certain level.

Answer (score 0):

1- If you predict you ordinal probit/logit modelinto you population, you will get scores of each group, and then you can make a rule based on the highest proba per group, in case of matching proba scores (i dont thik this will happen) you send up or down (randomly? or based on an specific question)
2-It seems that you are also concerned about the number of students in each group. So if this is an issue, why don't you create deciles/xtiles and assign each person to their groups? This solution, will create equal number of members.
This approach could be complemented with other rules, such as score below 25 do not get to go to class X and so forth.

hope it helps,

Comment: We're not concerned about the number of students in each group. We don't want to force a student into an inappropriate course level just to fill seats.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the aggregate score. There would usually be some gradation of 'hardness' in the questions that will add extra information to your analysis and there might also be some utility in matching the subject matter of the questions with the course options.

As a retired university academic I can say from experience that if you look at the relationships between success on each question and the aggregate score, and with indices of prior academic success and you will almost certainly find some interesting patterns that could help you in your allocations goal. You might also find occasionally a question that predicts backwards (i.e. a question where success correlates with lower performance overall), and bad questions that have no truly correct answer or more than one correct answer.

Before you do that, however, make sure that you define the criteria for 'good' and 'bad' allocations. Without clearly thought out criteria you cannot even define 'optimal', much less achieve it.

Comment: Instead of using the aggregate score, would you recommend using each individual question in the logistic regression model, or are you referring to using them in a different way? Just trying to understand exactly how you'd not use the aggregate score. Also noting that we've done Cronbach's alpha and other internal consistency tests to weed out some bad questions, and we observe some weak patterns in the relationship between the question and the aggregate score.

Comment: I am suggesting that you should be using the available information rather than just using the easy numbers. Success in a hard question should count more towards the final index of academic success than success in a question that almost everyone gets right. Also note that some wrong answers are 'more wrong' than others; some represent failure to understand and some represent a failure to notice a clue or a trick. You need subject matter expert input for the meanings of each right and wrong answer for each question.

Comment: I agree that it would be ideal to use the available information, especially since some questions may be "harder" than others, and thus more correlated with higher courses, or vice versa. I'm curious about how you'd implement what you're suggesting.

Comment: How to implement it depends on what information you have and what you can distill from the data. At one end you might simply use a weighted aggregate score for your thresholding, where the weights reflect question hardness. At the other end you would use information about the conceptual strengths and skills to allocate students to courses that suit them or would help them to overcome weaknesses. There is no statistical method for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a cost function, generated a comprehensive list of potential cut-off scores that were at least $x$ points apart (to avoid overly sensitive course placements), and evaluated them all using the cost function.

The criteria is

- Avoid assigning a student to an overly advanced course.
- Avoid assigning a student to a course that doesn’t challenge them enough.
- If a student must be assigned to a course that doesn’t fit their abilities, it’s better to assign them to the next immediate level rather than skipping multiple levels. It’s also better to lean towards a lower level than a higher one.
- Adjust for class sizes, as some classes have had a significantly larger student count. Without this weighting, the larger courses will dominate the optimization process.

The cost function is

[image]

where for each set of cut-off scores that I evaluate, I assign each student $i$ a penalty $c_i$ that is weighted by the inverse of the size of their actual course placement $w(p_i)$. I sum the penalties across all $N$ students to get the cost $J$ of the cut-off scores. Lower costs indicate more optimal cut-off scores.

The penalty $c$ is calculated using

[image]

where I give each student a penalty that is based on the level difference Δ between their actual course placement ($p_i$) and the course placement predicted by their score ($d_i$). No penalty is given if both placements match. When the cut-off score suggests a higher course level than the student’s actual placement, the penalty is the square of the level difference, increasing as the course level increases. Conversely, if the score indicates a lower course level, the penalty is half the absolute difference, also increasing as the course level decreases. The penalty is steeper for upward misplacements, emphasizing the undesirability of placing a student into a course that is too high for their abilities.

Comment: Why do you add a weight $w(p_i)$ that is related to the class sizes? Is there a problem with small class sizes and if there's a problem how does that problem work in creating costs such as you describe? It seems a bit weird to apply such rule as, at the moment the current class sizes don't seem equal either. But also, it is not well expressed how class size should be taken into consideration. Is it a problem with the salary of the teachers, planning the roster, the sizes of the rooms? When I look at the graphs I would think that it is beneficial to just eliminate some classes.

Comment: I have made that recommendation, as the class sizes are not equal and there were only 2 students placed into one course, and the university cancels classes that have <6 students. For this round of cutoff score analysis, the weights help ensure that every class has a chance of being represented in the optimization process, regardless of whether they should be dropped, as that decision is not my call to make.

Comment: Do let me know if you have any further thoughts.